# How prove this matrix limit is $\lim_{m\to\infty}A^mx=\left(\dfrac{e}{n}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

**Question:**

> let $A$ is Doubly stochastic matrix,and the eigenvalue such
>   $$\lambda_{1}=1,|\lambda_{j}|<1,(j=2,3,\cdots,n)$$
>   and the $$e=(1,1,1,\cdots,1)^T$$
>   show that : for any 
>   vector $$x=(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n})^T,a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots +a_{n}=1,a_{i}\ge 0$$, have
>   $$\lim_{m\to\infty}A^mx=\left(\dfrac{e}{n}\right)$$

**where Doubly stochastic matrix some  properties and some result 
 can see [this](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=F4hRy1F1M6QC&pg=PA32&dq=Doubly+stochastic+matrix&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=51YoU7TfL6OFiAefp4CwBg&ved=0CF0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=Doubly%20stochastic%20matrix&f=false)**

My idea: since
$$|A|=\lambda_{2}\lambda_{3}\cdots\lambda_{n}<1$$

then I can't find this limit.

and can't solve this problem,

Comment: UStrangely phrased question since the RHS (AMD the answer) is the zero vector. They are asking you to prove that $A$ goes to the zero matrix, which might be an easier way to think about it.

Comment: Hello,if we have prove the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}A^n$ is $0$,but My question is $\dfrac{e}{n}$? why?  I think this Doubly stochastic matrix $A$ is usefull.Thank you

Comment: @nanchangjian, something seems to be wrong in your question: the limit *depending on* $\;n\;$ , $\;\lim_{n\to\infty} A^nx\;$ cannot be something with $\;n\;$ **again** ...!

Comment: @DonAntonio The variable on the LHS is irrelevant. The $n$ on the other side is the order of the matrix.

Comment: @nanchangjian Do you know about jordan normal form?

Comment: @GitGud, I see the *Very* same $\;n\;$ in both sides...and this is wrong. Perhaps you mean he could switch the LHS $\;n\;$ to $\;m\;$ , say?

Comment: @DonAntonio Do you agree that $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\left(A^nx\right)=\lim \limits_{m\to +\infty}\left(A^mx\right)$? If you do, there is no problem. If you don't, you can restate the problem as $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\left(A^mx\right)=\dfrac 1 n e$ because it is what's intended. **Edit:** that is what I mean, but I even assert that as it stands, it is OK.

Comment: Oh,sorry! I have edit.Thank you @DonAntonio

Comment: I believe there has to be some kind of restriction as to what vectors $x$ can be used. For $x = 0$, the LHS gives $0$ which is not equal to the RHS. Even more so, the LHS is linear in the vector $x$ and the RHS is constant which seems a little bit strange to me.

Comment: No, it is not ok, @GitGud: an expression $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=y_n$$ is intrinsically wrong if the RHS *actually* depends on $\;n\;$ as was the case in the question.

Comment: Now it is ok, @nanchangjian .

Comment: @DonAntonio The expression on the LHS has $n$ as a bounded variable, so it is OK. I think we will not convince each other of our views, so I suggest we stop this here as it is irrelevant for the question itself.

Comment: It is not a matter of "convincing", @GitGud: this is mathematics, no religion or politics. Just read the definition of limit in any decent calculus book, and what follows from it. And yes, it seems pointless to continue.

Comment: Don't suppose the eigenvalues are distinct by any chance?

Comment: It's related to the [Power Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration).

Comment: The projection of $\large x$ over the eigenvector-$1$ of $\large A$ can not be null and the $\large A$ eigenvalues should be distinct as @JpMcCarthy already asked ( according to the [Power Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, this is false.

Set $A:=\begin{bmatrix} \frac 1 2 & \frac 1 2\\ \frac 1 2 & \frac 1 2\end{bmatrix}$. Clearly $A^m=A$, for all $m\in \mathbb N$. Therefore with $x=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ -1\end{bmatrix}$ the equality doesn't hold.

You need to require $x\ge 0$.

---

**Layout of answer to the question post edit:** The proof goes something like this.

1. Firstly prove that the sequence $\left(A^m\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges. To do this you need to use the fact $1$ is the only eigenvalue of absolute value $1$, that $1$ is the largest eigenvalue and that its algebraic multiplicity is $1$.
2. The above implies that $\lim \limits_{m\to +\infty}\left(A^my\right)$ exists for all $y\in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$. Next, letting $B$ be $\lim \limits_{m\to +\infty}\left(A^m\right)$, prove that $AB=B$. This shows that $B$'s columns are all eigenvectors of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $1$.
3. Prove that $B$ is stochastic by columns. To do this first prove that for all $m\in \mathbb N$, $A^m$ is stochastic by columns.
4. From the fact that the columns of $B$ are eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalue $1$ and from the fact that $B$ is column-stochastic, using the hypothesis that $x$'s entries when summed equal $1$, conclude.

---

You could have asked me for more details instead of wasting reputation points in an unawarded bounty.

---

**Answer:** There exists $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $A$ is $n\times n$.

1. The sequence $\left(A^m\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges if, and only if, $\left(J^m\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$, where $J$ is a canonical jordan normal form of $A$. Since $1$ is the only eigenvalue of absolute value $1$, since $1$ is the largest eigenvalue and its algebraic multiplicity is $1$, it's clear from looking at the [powers of $J$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Powers) that $\left(J^m\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges and consequently so does $\left(A^m\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$.
2. Therefore $\lim \limits_{m\to +\infty}\left(A^my\right)$ exists for all $y\in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$. Define $B:=\lim \limits_{m\to +\infty}\left(A^m\right)$. Multiplying this definition by $A$ on the left yields $AB=A\lim \limits_{m\to +\infty}\left(A^m\right)=\lim \limits_{m\to +\infty}\left(A^{m+1}\right)=B$. Since $AB=A\left[\text{Col}_1(B)\mid \ldots \mid \text{Col}_n(B) \right]=\left[A\text{Col}_1(B)\mid \ldots \mid A\text{Col}_n(B) \right]$, it follows that the columns of $B$ are eigenvectors of $A$ associated to $1$.
3. Note that any $n\times n$ matrix $M$ is column-stochastic if, and only if, $(1,e)$ is an eigenpair of $M^T$. It's easy to prove by induction that $\forall m\in \mathbb N\left((A^m)^Te=e\right)$. This fact justifies the third equality below: $$B^Te=\lim \limits_{m\to +\infty}\left((A^m)^T\right)e=\lim \limits_{m\to +\infty}\left((A^m)^Te\right)=\lim \limits_{m\to +\infty}\left(e\right)=e.$$ Therefore $B$ is column-stochastic.
4. From 2. and 3. follows that $B=\left[\frac en\mid \ldots \mid \frac en\right]$. Given $x$ as in the question, it holds that $$\lim \limits_{m\to +\infty}\left(A^mx\right)=Bx=\begin{bmatrix}\frac 1 n(a_1+\ldots +a_n)\\ \vdots \\ \frac 1 n(a_1+\ldots +a_n)\end{bmatrix}=\dfrac e n.$$

Comment: Oh,Thank you, if $x\ge 0$,then this problem is true?

Comment: @nanchangjian Yes, it is.

Comment: Why? can you post you solution? Thank you

Comment: @nanchangjian I will not post a solution without knowing more about  what you know. I asked you something in the comments to the question which facilitates the answer and you ignored my question. For this reason, I don't post a solution.

Comment: sorry,sorry,I have edit this problem.

Comment: @nanchangjian You still haven't replied to my question in the comments.

Comment: sorry,My English is poor,and I am not understand your meaning

Comment: @nanchangjian Do you know about jordan normal form?

Comment: Git Gud,your solution seems very beautiful! but if $B=\left[\frac en\mid \ldots \mid \frac en\right]$ how to ensure $B^{T}e=e$ ? i can not understand many steps in your proof! your method use stochastic matrix! but as i remember, this question is for the students in linear algebra's class! maybe your difficult reasoning is excess ！

Comment: @user138827 In 3. I explained why $B^Te=e$. what equality don't you understand? The question itself talks about stochastic matrices, I didn't introduce the term, the OP did.